# Routes's conflicts between nodejs and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I'm using NodeJS, gulp and Angular with ui-router, and now when I configure angular to remove the tag (#) from the routes, I get the next problem, Angular's routes not works and navigator show this message:

**Cannot GET /access**

Can I limit nodeJs for so that it only responds to calls under certain route?

E.g: **localhost:3000/api/***

Or i need to limit this performance with node and gulp ports.

Comment: It would be easier to solve your problem if you could [create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that node.js is attempting to serve the routes.

You can fix this by creatg a catch-all handler that runs after your Node.js routes (i.e. your API calls, etc.).

Assuming you're using express, do something like this in your server.js file:

```
app = express();
app.use(app.router); // handles all your express routes

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); // will execute angular code
});
```

Comment: Hello,Angular its working but only if not reload the pageand I want  to limit nodeJs's routes like this:
 /api/user
 /api/sesion

I don't know if my question has logic or not.

Comment: What is serving your Angular files? Apache? Node? NGINX? I can give you the code to fix this for either

Comment: I am using no de to serve the files

Comment: You will need to restart the node server after making changes, unless you use something like livereload or browsersync